# Maven dependency spring-web vs spring-webmvc

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

What is the difference between the following dependencies?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

vs

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If I include `spring-webmvc` alone then `spring-web` is implicitly added.

When should we use `spring-web` alone?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`spring-web` provides core HTTP integration, including some handy Servlet filters, Spring HTTP Invoker, infrastructure to integrate with other web frameworks and HTTP technologies e.g. Hessian, Burlap.

`spring-webmvc` is an implementation of Spring MVC. `spring-webmvc` [depends on](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom) on `spring-web`, thus including it will transitively add `spring-web`. You don't have to add `spring-web` explicitly.

You should depend only on `spring-web` if you don't use Spring MVC but want to take advantage of other web-related technologies that Spring supports.

Comment: Agree, +1. But rare case scenario: Including `spring-webmvc` inturn adds `spring-web`, but say if you have spring-webmvc version as 4.0.2, and you add another dependency say `swagger-springmvc` version of 0.8.8, then it adds `spring-web` version of 3.2.x. In this case you might get class not found exceptions, So  here, you have to explicitly add `spring-web` and version as 4.0.2. I encountered this today

Comment: @spiderman I would exclude the transitive `spring-web` dependency in `swagger-springmvc`

Comment: @tomasz-nurkiewicz  what's difference between spring-jms and spring-messaging module

Comment: When you want to build an application which will be a rest api and you will not need view (jsp) at all, what you should use? spring-web or spring-webmvc?

Comment: @MohammadEghlima in this case use spring-web

Answer (score 12):

From the official doc:
The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context. It also contains an HTTP client and the web-related parts of Spring’s remoting support.

The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation for web applications. Spring’s MVC framework provides a clean separation between domain model code and web forms and integrates with all of the other features of the Spring Framework.

The spring-webmvc-portlet module (also known as the Web-Portlet module) provides the MVC implementation to be used in a Portlet environment and mirrors the functionality of the Servlet-based spring-webmvc module.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.22.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-web