# spring-mvc vs spring-webmvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In which case we have to choose Spring MVC and in which cases we need to select Spring WEB MVC.

Comment: They're the same thing. You might use the latter one to specify that you're not using webflow.

Comment: They are the same term, WEB is often omitted because it's obvious.

Comment: maybe you meant [the difference between `spring-web` and `spring-webmvc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533700/maven-dependency-spring-web-vs-spring-webmvc)