# The relationship between spring-web and spring-webmvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I found @Controller and @GetMapping in spring-web, but only use these two annotations, not using DispatcherServlet how to receive requests, why these two annotations are not placed in spring-webmvc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533700/maven-dependency-spring-web-vs-spring-webmvc

Answer (score 0):

Many use Spring Boot for building REST-APIs, and then consume those APIs from other backend services or JavaScript based web GUIs. In that case you want the Spring Web package to be able to create your controller's but don't need the MVC parts. That's why they have put the MVC parts in its own package.